# Code from target folder in java spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, directory, target, java-io

I have generated a zip file in target folder using a maven-plugin, and now I aim to bring/take/read that zip file into a java class as logic need that zip for further process
I tried with every possible way by providing paths to File f  = new File(path);
but everytime when I check with f.exists() or f.isFile() it gives false as most probably it is not able to find zip at that path,
So I am not clear how and what path to give and no use cases are given in SO as well
Can some one help.

tried with every suggested way
Resource and resourceLoader cannot be used as its only used when we read something from src/main/resources, used File of java.io but failed everytime
can someone explain what and how paths are given to read something from target folder in java spring boot

Comment: It depends on how the app is executed.  When running the app, what is the current directory?  Is the target directory available relative to that current directory?

Comment: how does ur path look like, which one u tried? everything you read is from the clsspath which in mvn all is under target. the sources are not part of the cp only the compiled/copied artifacts. so check your target folder after built, if its all there u expect

Comment: The `target` directory is where build artifacts are created when a build is run; as such, the `target` directory will not exist anywhere except the build machine.  Resource files are normally added to the `resource` directory and will be included in the jar when built.  You can then access resource files in the jar via a classloader.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting your question a little, it sounds like you have a resource file that you want to access at runtime and that that resource file will not change after a build.

Resource files should be added to the `src/main/resources`; doing so will add the resource files into the root of the jar when it is built.

If you want the resource file to be in a directory within the jar, then just create that directory structure under the resources directory.

For example, if you want the resource file to be in `some/directory`, then you would put the resource file in `src/main/resources/some/directory`.

When you access the resource file, you do so from the classpath using either [ClassLoader.getResource(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) or [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

For example, if I had a resource file called `my-resources.txt`, in `src/main/resources/some/directory`, the following would load and print this file from an `Application.class`:

```
public class Application
{
  private static final String RESOURCE_FILE = "some/directory/my-resources.txt";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    try (
      InputStream in = Application.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_FILE);
      BufferedReader reader = in != null ? new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)) : null;
    )
    {
      if (in == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to find: " + RESOURCE_FILE);

      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
}
```